# UITableView does not appear

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am using xCode 4.2 and storyboard.  I have a TabBarController that links to a UITableViewController, and each cell in the first TableViewController is suppose to produce another table view in a second TableViewController. 
The second controller is called PhotoListController and the calling method is listed below.  The problem is that the second Table View never appears.  I have checked the navigation controller and it is not null.  I know the view exists because if I add it to the current view, as a subview, it appears and overlaps the current view. I also added an NSLog statement in viewDidLoad of the PhotoListViewController class and it is getting to that method.  I have been at this for hours with no luck.  Any help would be appreciated.  I'm not sure if the errors stems from this code but here it is:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PhotoListViewController *plvc = [[PhotoListViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

    [plvc viewWillAppear:YES];   // without this line it never gets to viewDidLoad in     PhotoListViewContrller.m
    [nav pushViewController:plvc animated:YES];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    PhotoListViewController *plvc = [[PhotoListViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:plvc];

    [plvc viewWillAppear:YES];   // without this line it never gets to viewDidLoad in     PhotoListViewContrller.m
    [nav pushViewController:plvc animated:YES];
```

Comment: I have changed the second Line

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be creating a new nav controller in that method.  You don't add that nav controller to the view controller hierarchy so of course it doesn't get displayed and neither does the photo list view controller.

The nav controller should be in your storyboard.  Your storyboard should have a tab bar controller as its initial view controller.  One of the tabs in the tab bar should have a navigation controller attached to it.  The navigation controller's root view controller should be your main table view controller.  Then in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, you just create your `PhotoListViewController` and push it by saying this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:pvlc animated:YES];
```

You should never call `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: Rob, Thanks so much, that did it.  I went back and started fresh with a new storyboard and set it up as you said and it worked fine. Thanks again